# why basename does not work in unlink()

Tags: php

I have a strange issue:
I am trying to unlink a file from a subfolder.

So the subfolder is `folder1`
My unlink looks like this:

```
unlink("uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/".'folder1/'.$_GET['delete']);
```

Result: he deletes the file out of the folder.

To catch the foldername, i use basename();

This shows me my current dir: `basename($dir);`

When i echo `basename($dir);` het outputs: `folder1`

So i put the basename in the unlink like this:

```
   unlink("uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/".basename($dir).'/'.$_GET['delete']);
```

Result: i cannot delete the file anymore!

`basename($dir) == folder1`

What is going wrong?

Comment: I would extract the entire string to a variable and echo it to see what's really going on.

Comment: `echo "uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/".basename($dir).'/Penguins.jpg';` shows me `uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1/Penguins.jpg` (the file is Pinguins.jpg). So this is correct! I have no idea why basename does not work

Comment: what error or warning are you receiving?

Comment: Hard to help you without seeing some more code. You'll have to debug. Extract both the string with basename($dir) and the one without. Confirm that the one without works. Compare the strings. etc

Comment: well: `echo basename($dir);`  outputs: `folder1` The complete outputted string is exactly the same

Comment: Just for debugging / testing - you can do a `file_exists(unlink("uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/".basename($dir).'/'.$_GET['delete']))` call to check if the path is even correct or not. Another good check will be comparing the file path as you get from variables vs. as you type the whole path.

Comment: I did some testing and the problem seems to be the subfolder in which the file is. This works fine: `unlink("uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1/Penguins.jpg");` This works also fine: `unlink("uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1/".$_GET['delete']);` This works also fine: `unlink('uploads/sfm/'.$UserID.'/folder1/'.$_GET['delete']);` (the hash = $UserID). When i basename($dir) echo he outputs: `folder1` But this does not work anymore: `unlink("uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/".basename($dir).'/'.$_GET['delete']);` So the problem is the basename();